# Sending cloud message by using only API key provided from google developer console

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

**GCM** is old way and deprecated, but I still feel comfort on using it.  So, I would like to know if there is any site from where we can sent cloud message to all those devices depending upon **api key** from developer console but not using deviceregistrationkey.  By using **device registration** id and api key there are many sites from where we can sent cloud message.  But I want the site that uses only **api key**.

Note:- Site http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html needs **api key** as well as **device registration id**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, you need to register to enable GCM. As described in [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) and [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options), registration token is an ID issued by the GCM connection servers to the client app that allows it to receive messages.

Comment: Hi Teyam, Yes Your are right about IDs but my question need different answer. BTY Thanks!